# I’m lost, can you find me?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

I am at the furthest distance possible of a major city located 7.53481e-11 parsecs from Canberra.

I am at a municipality with over a thousand inhabitants.

Now where am I?

Hint 1

> Antipodes

Hint 2

> One of the cities is a capital

Comment: I don't understand the question... are you supposed to find a major city located 7.53481e-11 parsecs from Canberra (which looks like rot13(puevfgpuhepu arj mrnynaq), and then find a small town that is the furthest distance from that city?

Comment: @SQLnoob, think rot13(Nagvcbqrf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in Spanish municipal

> Alaejos

which is an antipode to

> capital of New Zealand, Wellington